# Definition of "operator", and by extension "operand", in Python terminology

Tags: python, computer-science, terminology, formal-languages, operands

Is this quote correct?

> `fot += [duk]` is an assignment in Python, actually a shortening of `fot = fot + [duk]`
> `fot` and `[duk]` are **not** operands in `fot += [duk]`
> however, they are operands in `fot + [duk]`

##### Background:

I'm currently substituting as lecturer in an undergraduate course in introductory programming using Python as teaching language. I was going through some materials covering a teaching exercise about programming terminology that they've been doing in this course the last few years. The quote above comes from a list of common mistakes that the students have made during the exercise previous years. I've translated it from the original Swedish and added emphasis and formatting.

In Python `+=` is called one of the augmented assignment *operators* and in my mind, if something is an operator, whatever it operates on is an *operand*. I.e. `fot` and `[duk]` above are operands of the `+=` operator. However, it's been 15 years since I took a course on programming languages from a more formal point of view, so I might have forgotten a lot of important details that matters in this case. Mainly, I'm thinking that something about assignment being a statement might affect how we define *operators* and *operands*, but I'm basically guessing in that regard.

##### My research thus far

I started digging through the Python Language Reference and I think that the reason for the quote above might be found in [Section 2.5](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators) which covers lexical analysis and lists the set of tokens defined as operators in that context. That list does not include `+=` (nor the regular assignment operator `=`). Instead they are listed in [Section 2.6](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters) which covers delimiters. (However, this section does refer to `+=` as an "augmented assignment operator" so it's already getting muddy.)

Further, in [Section 7.2](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), which covers assignment statements, `=` is implicitly referred to as "the assignment operator". A close reading of [Section 7.2.1], which specifically covers augmented assignment, contains the following quote [emphasis mine]:

> An augmented assignment evaluates the target (which, unlike normal assignment statements, cannot be an unpacking) and the expression list, performs the binary operation specific to the type of assignment on the two **operands**, and assigns the result to the original target. The target is only evaluated once.

That quote seems to strengthen my point. It explicitly uses the word *operands* in the context of `+=`. However, it could be interpreted as the two tokens being operands of "the binary operation specific to the type of assignment" not as being operands of the augmented assignment itself. That might even be what the third line of the original quote is saying.

Coincidentally, further reading of Section 7.2.1 reveals that, regardless of lines 2 and 3, the first line from the quote above isn't quite right.

> Unlike normal assignments, augmented assignments evaluate the left-hand side *before* evaluating the right-hand side.

I.e. `fot += [duk]` is not simply a macro that is expanded into `fot = fot + [duk]`, it actually has slightly different semantics.

One guess is that whoever wrote the original quote above only looked at Section 2.5 and noted that `+=` wasn't in the list of operators in the context of tokenization, and/or remembered that `=` is usually not considered an operator in math, and stopped there. However, it took me looking through multiple sections and searching for references to "operator" and "operand" to come this far and I'm still not certain. I most definitely did not read the whole Python Language Reference, though. There might be something else that affects the status of `fot` and `[duk]` as operands or not in the context of `fot += [duk]`.

Your thoughts?

Comment: What is the point of this distinction? `+=` is an assignment operator (i.e. not an expression operator). Why does it matter where it's parameters are called operands? I.e. what are the implications if they aren't operands? It is very important to mention that `a += a` is not a shorthand for `a = a + b`, that is one of the most common mistakes I am aware of.

Comment: The real semantics of `x += y` are essentially as follows: if `x.__iadd__` is defined, it's equivalent to `x = x.__iadd__(y)`; otherwise, it falls back to `x = x.__add__(y)`.

Comment: If you're asking how to explain this to students, [cseducators.se] would probably be a better place to ask. It's not a distinction that needs to be made in day-to-day programming.

Comment: I suspect the distinction you're looking for is between statements and expressions. In Python, assignments are statements, not expressions, so `=` and `+=` are not operators in the same way that `==` and `+` are. They're closer to keywords like `for` and `def`.

Comment: It is worth noting that x += 1 is **usually** equivalent to x = x +1 but is in fact internally different calling `__iadd__` and `__add__`  respectively. This only matters when the object is mutable and allows in-place addition (specifically Lists and Dictionary Values and maybe for user-defined Classes) because objects with the same reference will also be changed. So
a1 = [1, 2, 3];
a2 = a1
Then a1 += [4] is NOT the same as a1 = a1 + [4] because the former changes a2 as well.

Comment: From what I can tell from a quick look, the docs don't use a consistent definition of "operator". But if you look at more practical sections like the [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module and [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), they seem to use "operator" something like "a symbol or pattern of symbols involved in an **expression**".

Comment: See also: ["the various assignment operators (`=`, `+=` etc) \[...\] are not truly operators but syntactic delimiters in assignment statements."](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-s-up-with-the-comma-operator-s-precedence)

Comment: @MegaIng That was basically my reaction, too. I don't understand why you would make a distinction between "operands" of expression operators and "supposedly not-operands" of statement operators. The fact that the explanation for this "common mistake" itself contained a common mistake (missing the difference between assignment and augmented assignment when applied to mutable types) made me even more skeptical.

Comment: @Barmar I am aware of the important distinction between expressions and statements in Python. What I don't understand is why that distinction would mean that only expression operators have operands, while statement operators don't. Interestingly, I also found the following in 7.2.1 (emphasis mine): "An augmented assignment _expression_ like `x += 1`[...]" This might just be a typo but that phrasing has been there since the reference for 2.6 at least.

Comment: Also @Barmar, thanks for pointing me towards [Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com). I'm definitely going to have a look around there.

Comment: It's an arbitrary distinction that the source you're quoting makes. They're using the term "operator" for to refer to syntax that acts like function calls, and operands are analogous to function arguments.